# How I could add dir to $PATH in Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

I want to write a Makefile which would run tests. Test are in a directory './tests' and executable files to be tested are in the directory './bin'.

When I run the tests, they don't see the exec files, as the directory ./bin is not in the $PATH.

When I do something like this:

```
EXPORT PATH=bin:$PATH
make test
```

everything works. However I need to change the $PATH in the Makefile.

Simple Makefile content:

```
test all:
    PATH=bin:${PATH}
    @echo $(PATH)
    x
```

It prints the path correctly, however it doesn't find the file x.

When I do this manually:

```
$ export PATH=bin:$PATH
$ x
```

everything is OK then.

How could I change the $PATH in the Makefile?

Comment: Can you not just call the tests from the executable directory like `../test/test_to_run`? Sorry if I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I want this file to be visible to the tests normally. I don't want to play with the directories, as I refactoring that would be a nighmare.

Comment: The only way you can come close to this is to have the makefile write out a shell script containing the variable decls and then have the parent shell source that script with `.`. This is probably impractical however.

Comment: I believe that http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/adding-directory-to-path-through-makefile is a **very different** (stupid) question, unlike yours.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Did you try [`export` directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion) of Make itself (assuming that you use GNU Make)?

```
export PATH := bin:$(PATH)

test all:
    x
```

Also, there is a bug in you example:

```
test all:
    PATH=bin:${PATH}
    @echo $(PATH)
    x
```

First, the value being `echo`ed is an expansion of `PATH` variable performed by Make, not the shell. If it prints the expected value then, I guess, you've set `PATH` variable somewhere earlier in your Makefile, or in a shell that invoked Make. To prevent such behavior you should escape dollars:

```
test all:
    PATH=bin:$$PATH
    @echo $$PATH
    x
```

Second, in any case this won't work because Make executes each line of the recipe in a [separate shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution). This can be changed by writing the recipe in a single line:

```
test all:
    export PATH=bin:$$PATH; echo $$PATH; x
```

Comment: `$(PATH)` will get set to the value of `PATH` of the shell invoking make. As per [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html), "Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value."

Comment: The export directive worked for me (thanks!), but only after I installed GNU Make 4.3. In version 3.81 (the default on macOS Catalina), the updated `PATH` is correctly reflected in variables (`echo $(PATH)`) and within commands' environments (`env`, `which python`, `bash -c python`), but does not seem to be used when locating the executable for the command: the command `python` still runs the Python executable on the original `PATH`.

Answer (score 40):

By design `make` parser executes lines in a separate shell invocations, that's why changing variable (e.g. `PATH`) in one line, the change may not be applied for the next lines (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48831622/55075)).

One way to workaround this problem, is to convert multiple commands into a single line (separated by `;`), or use [One Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) special target (`.ONESHELL`, as of GNU Make 3.82).

Alternatively you can provide `PATH` variable at the time when shell is invoked. For example:

```
PATH  := $(PATH):$(PWD)/bin:/my/other/path
SHELL := env PATH=$(PATH) /bin/bash
```

Comment: This is the best, because it works even with `$(shell)` invocations! :D
Example: https://pastebin.com/Pii8pmkD

Comment: On dev.azure I get: env: ‘env’: No such file or directory; Works locally ;/

Comment: Does not work on Debian 10 with make 4.2: make: env PATH=<path>  /bin/sh: Command not found. Using export works. Make sure to use $(HOME) and not ~ for a path in the home dir.

Comment: @kenorb
looking for this  `export SHELL := env VAR="xxx" /bin/bash`, worked !  thanks

Comment: This does not work for me. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77925210/712765) for why.

Answer (score 27):

Path changes appear to be persistent if you set the SHELL variable in your makefile first:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
PATH := bin:$(PATH)

test all:
    x
```

I don't know if this is desired behavior or not.

Comment: Yeah, this does indeed do what the OP wanted...but is it a feature or a bug? Even after reading the [make manual's SHELL section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) I'm not sure.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me either. `which` and `env` now pick up the new PATH, but directly executing a binary is still not found in the modified PATH, only in the original one.

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do is supply the path to the executable explicitly:

```
EXE=./bin/
...
test all:
    $(EXE)x
```

I also use this technique to run non-native binaries under an emulator like QEMU if I'm cross compiling:

```
EXE = qemu-mips ./bin/
```

If make is using the sh shell, this should work:

```
test all:
    PATH=bin:$PATH x
```

Comment: Yep, cool soulution, however I've got my tests written in perl and I need to call the exe from the perl script, not directly from makefile. I've got to rethink the whole testing of this stuff :)

Comment: Gotcha. How about setting PATH on the command line itself? See the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

In many versions of Gnu Make, such as v3.81 which is shipped by Apple on macOS, changes to the `PATH` variable inside the Makefile affect the shells `make` launches, but do not affect `make` itself. It is not clear if this is a bug or a feature.

For example, with this Makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/sh

TESTDIR = /tmp/testdir
export PATH := $(TESTDIR):$(PATH)

.PHONY: all prepare internal shell clean

all: prepare shell internal clean

prepare:
    @mkdir -p $(TESTDIR)
    @cp /bin/date $(TESTDIR)/mydate
    @chmod +x $(TESTDIR)/mydate

# This recipe forces `make` to invoke a shell by using command substitution
# or boolean operation
shell: prepare
    @echo "In target: shell"
    @printf "mydate is %s\n" "$$(mydate -I -u)"
    @: && mydate -I -u
    @echo "End target: shell"

# This is invoked directly by `make` and does not pick up the change in PATH
internal: prepare
    @echo "In target: internal"
    mydate -I -u
    @echo "End target: internal"

clean:
    rm -rf $(TESTDIR)
```

You will find that `make shell` works, but `make internal` does not.

The fact that the difference is between whether a shell is launched or not can lead to some very confusing behavior, as you can now see.

```
$ make
In target: shell
mydate is 2024-02-02
2024-02-02
End target: shell
In target: internal
mydate -I -u
make: mydate: No such file or directory
make: *** [internal] Error 1
```

Answer (score -3):

To set the `PATH` variable, within the Makefile only, use something like:

```
PATH := $(PATH):/my/dir

test:
@echo my new PATH = $(PATH)
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want. I've updated the question withe examples of what I want to achieve.