# makefile pathing issues on OSX

Tags: makefile

OK, I thought I would try one last update and see if it gets me anywhere. I've created a very small test case. This should not build anything, it just tests the path settings. Also I've setup the path so there are no spaces. The is the smallest, simplest test case I could come up with.

This makefile will set the path, echo the path, run `avr-gcc -v` with the full path specified and then try to run it without the full path specified. It should find `avr-gcc` in the path on the second try, but *does not*.

**makefile**

```
TOOLCHAIN := /Users/justinzaun/Desktop/AVRBuilder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain


PATH := ${TOOLCHAIN}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH


all:
    @echo ${PATH}
    @echo --------
    "${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/avr-gcc" -v
    @echo --------
    avr-gcc -v
```

**output**

```
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$ make
/Users/justinzaun/Desktop/AVRBuilder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
--------
"/Users/justinzaun/Desktop/AVRBuilder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/avr-gcc" -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/Users/justinzaun/Desktop/AVRBuilder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/avr-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Users/justinzaun/Desktop/AVRBuilder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/4.6.3/lto-wrapper
Target: avr
Configured with: /Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../gcc/configure --prefix=/Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../build/ --exec-prefix=/Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../build/ --datadir=/Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../build/ --target=avr --enable-languages=c,objc,c++ --disable-libssp --disable-lto --disable-nls --disable-libgomp --disable-gdbtk --disable-threads --enable-poison-system-directories
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.6.3 (GCC) 
--------
avr-gcc -v
make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$
```

---

---

***Original Question***

I'm trying to set the path from within the makefile. I can't seem to do this on OSX. Setting the path with `PATH := /new/bin/:$(PATH)` does not work. See my makefile below.

**makefile**

```
PROJECTNAME = Untitled

# Name of target controller
# (e.g. 'at90s8515', see the available avr-gcc mmcu
# options for possible values)
MCU = atmega640

# id to use with programmer
# default: PROGRAMMER_MCU=$(MCU)
# In case the programer used, e.g avrdude, doesn't
# accept the same MCU name as avr-gcc (for example
# for ATmega8s, avr-gcc expects 'atmega8' and 
# avrdude requires 'm8')
PROGRAMMER_MCU = $(MCU)

# Source files
# List C/C++/Assembly source files:
# (list all files to compile, e.g. 'a.c b.cpp as.S'):
# Use .cc, .cpp or .C suffix for C++ files, use .S
# (NOT .s !!!) for assembly source code files.
PRJSRC = main.c   \
         utils.c

# additional includes (e.g. -I/path/to/mydir)
INC = 

# libraries to link in (e.g. -lmylib)
LIBS = 

# Optimization level,
# use s (size opt), 1, 2, 3 or 0 (off)
OPTLEVEL = s



### You should not have to touch anything below this line ###



PATH := /Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR\ Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$(PATH)
CPATH := /Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR\ Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/include


# HEXFORMAT -- format for .hex file output
HEXFORMAT = ihex

# compiler
CFLAGS = -I. $(INC) -g -mmcu=$(MCU) -O$(OPTLEVEL)  \
         -fpack-struct -fshort-enums               \
         -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char      \
         -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes                 \
         -Wa,-ahlms=$(firstword                    \
                    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.c=.lst)))

# c++ specific flags
CPPFLAGS = -fno-exceptions                 \
           -Wa,-ahlms=$(firstword          \
           $(filter %.lst, $(<:.cpp=.lst)) \
           $(filter %.lst, $(<:.cc=.lst))  \
           $(filter %.lst, $(<:.C=.lst)))

# assembler
ASMFLAGS = -I. $(INC) -mmcu=$(MCU)          \
           -x assembler-with-cpp            \
           -Wa,-gstabs,-ahlms=$(firstword   \
           $(<:.S=.lst) $(<.s=.lst))

# linker
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map,$(TRG).map -mmcu=$(MCU)  \
          -lm $(LIBS)

##### executables ####
CC=avr-gcc
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP=avr-objdump
SIZE=avr-size
AVRDUDE=avrdude
REMOVE=rm -f

##### automatic target names ####
TRG=$(PROJECTNAME).out
DUMPTRG=$(PROJECTNAME).s

HEXROMTRG=$(PROJECTNAME).hex
HEXTRG=$(HEXROMTRG) $(PROJECTNAME).ee.hex

# Start by splitting source files by type
#  C++
CPPFILES=$(filter %.cpp, $(PRJSRC))
CCFILES=$(filter %.cc, $(PRJSRC))
BIGCFILES=$(filter %.C, $(PRJSRC))
#  C
CFILES=$(filter %.c, $(PRJSRC))
#  Assembly
ASMFILES=$(filter %.S, $(PRJSRC))

# List all object files we need to create
OBJDEPS=$(CFILES:.c=.o)     \
        $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o) \
        $(BIGCFILES:.C=.o)  \
        $(CCFILES:.cc=.o)   \
        $(ASMFILES:.S=.o)

# Define all lst files.
LST=$(filter %.lst, $(OBJDEPS:.o=.lst))

# All the possible generated assembly
# files (.s files)
GENASMFILES=$(filter %.s, $(OBJDEPS:.o=.s))

.SUFFIXES : .c .cc .cpp .C .o .out .s .S \
            .hex .ee.hex .h .hh .hpp

# Make targets:
# all, disasm, stats, hex, writeflash/install, clean
all: $(TRG)

$(TRG): $(OBJDEPS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TRG) $(OBJDEPS)

#### Generating assembly ####
# asm from C
%.s: %.c
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# asm from (hand coded) asm
%.s: %.S
    $(CC) -S $(ASMFLAGS) $< > $@

# asm from C++
.cpp.s .cc.s .C.s :
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

#### Generating object files ####
# object from C
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# object from C++ (.cc, .cpp, .C files)
.cc.o .cpp.o .C.o :
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# object from asm
.S.o :
    $(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#### Generating hex files ####
# hex files from elf
.out.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text                    \
               -j .data                    \
               -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@

.out.ee.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom                     \
               --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 \
               -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@

#### Information ####
info:
    @echo PATH:
    @echo "$(PATH)"
    $(CC) -v
    which $(CC)

#### Cleanup ####
clean:
    $(REMOVE) $(TRG) $(TRG).map $(DUMPTRG)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDEPS)
    $(REMOVE) $(LST)
    $(REMOVE) $(GENASMFILES)
    $(REMOVE) $(HEXTRG)
```

**error**

```
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$ make
avr-gcc -I.  -g -mmcu=atmega640 -Os -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-ahlms=main.lst -c main.c -o main.o
make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$
```

If I change my `CC=` to include the full path:

```
CC=/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR\ Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/avr-gcc
```

then it finds it, but this doesn't seem the correct way to do things. For instance its trying to use the system `as` not the one in the correct path.

**update** - Just to be sure, I'm adding the output of my `ls` command too so everyone knows the file exist. Also I've added a make info target to the makefile and showing that output as well.

```
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$ ls /Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR\ Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin
ar      avr-elfedit avr-man     avr-strip   objcopy
as      avr-g++     avr-nm      avrdude     objdump
avr-addr2line   avr-gcc     avr-objcopy c++     ranlib
avr-ar      avr-gcc-4.6.3   avr-objdump g++     strip
avr-as      avr-gcov    avr-ranlib  gcc
avr-c++     avr-gprof   avr-readelf ld
avr-c++filt avr-ld      avr-size    ld.bfd
avr-cpp     avr-ld.bfd  avr-strings nm
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$
```

Output of `make info` with the `\` in my path

```
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$ make info
PATH:
/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR\ Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
avr-gcc -v
make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [info] Error 1
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$
```

Output of `make info` with the `\` not in my path

```
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$ make info
PATH:
/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
avr-gcc -v
make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [info] Error 1
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$
```

**update** - When I have my `CC` set to include the full path as described above, this is the result of `make info`.

```
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$ make info
PATH:
/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR\ Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/avr-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/avr-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/4.6.3/lto-wrapper
Target: avr
Configured with: /Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../gcc/configure --prefix=/Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../build/ --exec-prefix=/Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../build/ --datadir=/Users/justinzaun/Development/AVRBuilder/Packages/gccobj/../build/ --target=avr --enable-languages=c,objc,c++ --disable-libssp --disable-lto --disable-nls --disable-libgomp --disable-gdbtk --disable-threads --enable-poison-system-directories
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.6.3 (GCC) 
which /Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR\ Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/avr-gcc
/Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin/avr-gcc
JUSTINs-MacBook-Air:Untitled justinzaun$
```

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest solution be to install the tools into a directory without a blank space in the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example on OSX and Linux, and got the same results that you did.  I don't quite understand why that isn't working (and would love to know), but I do have two workarounds that might help.

**export SHELL**

Instead of setting the PATH in your Makefile, override the SHELL like this:

```
export SHELL=/Users/whatever/avr-dir/wrapper
```

Here's a possible version of that wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/Users/whatever/avr-dir:${PATH}"
/bin/bash "$@"
```

Make will invoke this wrapper to run each line of yoru recipes.  This is a little ugly, but it did work for me on OSX.

**Outside**

Fix the PATH outside of make.  Perhaps create a script that you run once per login that fixes the PATH in your shell, or create a small script (I usually call it `mk`) that fixes the PATH and then invokes make passing along any parameters.  Here's an exmaple:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/Users/whatever/avr-dir:${PATH}" exec make "$@"
```

I know you asked for a Makefile solution, but I thought I would mention this option anyway.  It is just my opinion, but things like PATHs tend to be machine specific (and not project specific), and I prefer to keep them separate from source code.

Comment: You sir are a life saver. I have no idea *why* the path can not be set from within the makefile but your `SHELL=` workaround works. I'm gonna mark this as correct as it lets me compile with my toolchain, albeit using a workaround to set the path. The fact that Xcode can call this makefile and find avr-gcc solved my main issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (for paths without whitespace) on GNU/Linux, with any version of GNU make from 3.81 to 4.1 (you don't say what version you're using).  I have heard from others that OSX ships a modified version of GNU make which has some bugs in it that don't appear in the standard version of GNU make; maybe if you built your own GNU make from source it would work better.

Comment: @MadScientist  Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that `make` failed to find `avr-gcc`.  Your problem is in this line:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -mmcu=$(MCU) -c $(input) -o $(output)
```

Since `$(input)` and `$(output)` have not been defined your `avr-gcc` command-line is incomplete.  Try changing that line to this instead:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -mmcu=$(MCU) -c $< -o $@
```

`$<` and `$@` are *automatic* variables defined to mean "the first prerequisite" and "the output target", respectively.

Comment: the makefile may have been wrong but that was not the cause of the error. I've posted an updated makefile and error message. It still comes down to avr-gcc not being found in the path, what I can see it is there.

Comment: If the problem were that avr-gcc is not being found in the path, the error would be "Command not found", not "No such file or directory", and make's exit code would be 127, not 1.

Comment: -I'll look into other things them, just seems odd. main.c is there too.

Comment: I really think this is still a path issue, see my updated question. If I'm just missing something else and this isn't a path issue then I really don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem *is* that make is failing to find avr-gcc, and it's due to the `\` in your `PATH=` line.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo\ bar
$ cd /tmp/foo\ bar
$ (echo "#! /bin/sh"; echo "echo this got run") > execable
$ chmod +x execable
$ mkdir /tmp/tstmake; cd /tmp/tstmake
```

(now make a Makefile with contents as shown)

```
$ cat Makefile
PATH := /tmp/foo\ bar:$(PATH)

all:
        @echo path is "$(PATH)"
        execable
$ make
path is /tmp/foo\ bar:/Users/torek/bin.i386:/Users/torek/scripts:[snipped lots]
execable
make: execable: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
$ ed Makefile
71
1s/\\//p
PATH := /tmp/foo bar:$(PATH)
w
70
q
$ make
path is /tmp/foo bar:/Users/torek/bin.i386:/Users/torek/scripts:[snipped lots]
execable
this got run
```

---

Update: this is not the only problem, at least when I use my MBP to simulate the issue.  The remaining two are:

- `CPATH` also needs the backslash removed (this is a general rule about these := settings)
- `CPATH` needs to be explicitly `export`ed, by adding the line

  export CPATH

to the `Makefile`.

(The reason you need the backslash sometimes, but not other times, has to do with how many times the string gets passed expliclty to the shell: once when it's in `$(CC)` but zero times when it is an environment variable or part of `$(PATH)`.)

Comment: I've set my path line to `PATH := /Users/justinzaun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AVR_Builder-gxiykwiwjywvoagykxvmotvncbyd/Build/Products/Debug/AVR Builder.app/Contents/Resources/avrchain/bin:$(PATH)` but I still get `make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory`.  I'm adding the output of an ls command just so I know I'm not crazy.

Comment: Hmm.  When you have things set up so that manually invoking `avr-gcc` works, what does `which` (or `type -p`) say?  For instance on my MBP `which gcc` prints `/usr/bin/gcc`.  Also, it's interesting that I get `Command not found` rather than `No such file or directory`, definitely there is a clue there.

Comment: I added the result of `make info` with a hard coded CC. Is this the information you are looking for?

Comment: No, I was just wondering something that appears to be irrelevant.  I think I got it, let me edit the answer, there's two more missing steps!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this page didn't have a proper answer, I'll link to this page that does:

[How I could add dir to $PATH in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941110/how-i-could-add-dir-to-path-in-makefile/13468229#13468229)

For whatever reason OS X does not export PATH unless you set the SHELL variable too.

So:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
export PATH:=/foo/bar:$(PATH)
```

..would work.

Comment: this was just what I needed! it works!! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I just recently ran into this issue.  As other comments suggest, the version of `make` shipped with MacOS has some issues.  Build (as @MadScientist suggests above) or [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871732/using-gnu-make-4-x-on-osx) GNU make from Homebrew.  The installed version of `make` on my system is 3.81 and exhibits the same problem.  The version provided from Homebrew (version 4.3) works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using OSX. Figuring out an elegant solution may take a few iterations.

In the meantime try this kludge, and tell us the result:

```
CC=`avr-gcc`
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to update your PATH variable, then do:

```
export PATH=$(shell echo $${PATH}):<paths to add>
```

Example I did:

File : ./c/luckme.sh

```
echo "Hello Lucky Me ! "
```

Makefile :

```
export PATH=$(shell echo $${PATH}):c:.
all:
    @luckyme.sh
```

output of make:

```
~$ make
Hello Lucky Me !
```