# Using GNU Make 4.X on OSX

Tags: macos, homebrew, gnu-make

I'm following https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/getting_started/

which requires make. When I run the install scripts, the prompt tells me to use make 4.1 . I run `brew install erlang git homebrew/dupes/make`

then `brew unlink make && brew link make` but `which make` is still `/usr/bin` and `make -v` is 3.8.

How do I link to the correct, updated make?

EDIT

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
is the first line of my ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `PATH` so that `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of, i.e. **before** `/usr/bin` because **homebrew** puts its binaries in `/usr/local/bin`.

So, for a one-off command, you can run:

```
/usr/local/bin/make -v
```

but in general, you want to set your `PATH` in your `$HOME/.profile` or in `$HOME/.bash_profile` like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

In general, you will need to source your profile:

```
source ~/.profile
```

or log out and log back in again after changing it for it to take effect.

Comment: usr/local/Cellar/make/4.2.1/bin/gmake -v
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. shows me the versioning

Comment: "vim ~/.bash_profile" 72L, 3426C
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH -- first line

Comment: I will try with gmake as that is what brew installed

Comment: Don't run anything from `/usr/local/Cellar`, there will be a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` to the Cellar and that is the one you should use - otherwise you will get into all sorts of difficulty with different versions of packages. The idea of `homebrew` is that it keeps the symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` up-to-date for you.

Comment: Excellent - glad to be of service :-)