# Eclipse: where does it look for executables?

Tags: eclipse, ragel

I have a project that uses ragel for parsing. I get this error when I try to compile it.

/bin/sh: ragel: command not found

So I am guessing eclipse is looking at some path for ragel. Currently ragel is in /usr/local/bin. I am not able to find out where eclipse is trying to search for ragel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to launch ragel inside eclipse? (Are you using eclipse as a ragel editor?)

If so then you will want to look in

Run Menu->External Tools->External Tool Configurations

Look for a ragel entry under the Program category that specifies the run configuration for ragel.  There are a few places for paths and such.  Ensure these matach /usr/local/bin where you have ragel installed.

If that doesn't work, a back up hack:

Find eclipse binary

```
  sudo updatedb
  locate eclipse
```

Create a soft link from /usr/local/bin/ragel to the directory where the eclipse binary is..

Comment: I do not have ragel under the program category?

Comment: What button do you use in Eclipse to launch ragel?   Are you using a plugin or is this a custom version of Eclipse that is distributed with ragel..

Comment: I am using eclipse c/c++ and there is a make file which invokes ragel command I think. I am just trying to make from eclipse. It works if I make from command line though.

Comment: Try adding `/usr/local/bin` to the PATH by putting `export PATH := $(PATH):/usr/local/bin` into the makefile (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941110/how-i-could-add-dir-to-path-in-makefile).