# Create a build environment for "C" project to dynamically select folders during compile time

Tags: c, embedded, multiplatform, build-process-template

Lets say my folder structure is something like this ..

+-- Application 
| 
+-- MICRO_CONTROLLER_1
|
+-- MICRO_CONTROLLER_2
|
+-- MICRO_CONTROLLER_3

and i have a compile switch (  SELECT_MICRO)  set to  #define SELECT_MICRO == MICRO_CONTROLLER_1 , then my project should build application with driver files in MICRO_CONTROLLER_1 , similarly if #define SELECT_MICRO == MICRO_CONTROLLER_2 , then application should build application with driver files in MICRO_CONTROLLER_2

Please let me know if there  template to achieve the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can export that particular path of the folder you want to build and supply the path to the executable. You can get further info. in this thread.

[How I could add dir to $PATH in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941110/how-i-could-add-dir-to-path-in-makefile)

Or simply maintain different Makefiles to make different builds and use make -f  to run that particular makefile.

I hope this is what you finally want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would `define` your pre-processor definitions to tell the pre-processor to include only, for instance, MICRO_CONTROLLER_1 blocks of code and ignore everything else.

Something like the following should suffice:

```
#if defined(MICRO_CONTROLLER_1)
// Block of code that is only available to MICRO_CONTROLLER_1
#elif defined(MICRO_CONTROLLER_2)
// ...
// All other microcontrollers you are supporting would follow this structure.
#endif
```

Then you would need to `define` MICRO_CONTROLLER_1. If you're using an IDE for development, there is typically a project option for pre-processor directives. This is where you would `define` MICRO_CONTROLLER_1. You could then create different "configurations" - one for each of the microcontrollers you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

This can only work if the directories have only include files. #define is a preprocessor directive. If the directories have source files, you need to solve it at the build system layer, not the preprocessor layer.

Assuming it's just include files, you'd just `#include SELECT_MICRO # "Interface.h"`