# Setting PATH within Makefile on Mac OS X (but it works on Linux)

Tags: macos, makefile, gnu-make

I'm able to set PATH in a Makefile on Linux but not Mac OS X.  With OS X, the PATH gets set but doesn't get used.  Here's a demonstration:

On CentOS 6 with bash 4.1.2(1)-release and GNU Make 3.81

```
$ pwd
/tmp/experiment
$ find * -type f -ls
132133    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 tlim tlim      113 Aug 26 11:01 Makefile
132132    4 -rwxrwxr-x   1 tlim tlim       28 Aug 26 10:59 bin/myprog
$ cat Makefile 
export PATH := $(shell /bin/pwd)/bin:$(PATH)

what:
    @echo PATH=$$PATH
    @echo PATH=$(PATH)
    which myprog
    myprog
$ cat bin/myprog 
#!/bin/bash
echo HERE I AM.
$ make what
PATH=/tmp/experiment/bin:/usr/stack/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PATH=/tmp/experiment/bin:/usr/stack/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
which myprog
/tmp/experiment/bin/myprog
myprog
HERE I AM.
```

Here's the exact same files run on a Mac OS X 10.9.4 with GNU Make 3.81:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/experiment
$ find * -type f -ls
51838886        8 -rw-rw-r--    1 tal              wheel                 113 Aug 26 07:01 Makefile
51838887        8 -rwxrwxr-x    1 tal              wheel                  28 Aug 26 06:59 bin/myprog
$ cat Makefile 
export PATH := $(shell /bin/pwd)/bin:$(PATH)

what:
    @echo PATH=$$PATH
    @echo PATH=$(PATH)
    which myprog
    myprog
$ cat bin/myprog 
#!/bin/bash
echo HERE I AM.
$ make what
PATH=/tmp/experiment/bin:/Users/tal/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
PATH=/tmp/experiment/bin:/Users/tal/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
which myprog
/tmp/experiment/bin/myprog
myprog
make: myprog: No such file or directory
make: *** [what] Error 1
```

As you can see, the PATH is getting set and exported into the environment.  Both "echo $PATH" and "which myprog" show that the path is set.  However, when running "myprog" the shell can't find it.

*Update:* If I add these two lines to the `what` recipe in the Makefile:

```
@echo SHELL=$$SHELL
@echo SHELL=$(SHELL)
```

Both Linux and Mac output:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

Both have `SHELL` equal to `/bin/bash` in the environment before running `make`.  This makes me think that having `SHELL` set in Makefile is just magic and is one of the many reason that The GNU Make Manual says to always set `SHELL`.

Comment: And `/bin/bash` is the correct path for `bash` on OS X? Does the script work correctly if you run it as `./myprog` (from inside or outside of the makefile)?

Comment: Yes, /bin/bash is the correct path on both systems.  ./myprog runs without any problems.

Comment: And md5/etc. sums confirm the scripts are the same? There wasn't an accidental UTF-8 BOM inserted or conversion to non-unix newlines or anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the PATH variable is special and isn't exported unless ["SHELL" is also set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468229/71978).  In other words, if I add this one line to the Makefile it works on both Mac and Linux:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

This, of course, makes me wonder why the Mac is different.  Hopefully by documenting this here others that see this problem will also benefit. Plus, I'd like to know why the Mac is different, if it really is.

Comment: Does using `SHELL=/bin/sh` work? That is is the issue the setting of `SHELL` or the shell being used? (Perhaps OS X `/bin/sh` does not respect environmental values of `PATH`.)

Comment: Hmmm, not a _make_ issue IMHO. `which` just says there is an executable file with the given name on your `$PATH`, it doesn't say that that file can be executed. What could cause it to fail to load? A host of issues. Dependent shared library files maybe. Does your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` include `.`? Not even sure the Mac uses `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, probably might need access to the right frameworks. _bash_ presumably sets thing up correctly for you.