# How to enter a parent directory in Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I've got the following `Makefile` (GNU Make 3.81):

```
CWD:=$(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

all:
        pwd
        cd "$(CWD)/.."
        pwd
        cd ".."
        pwd
```

Here is the output:

```
$ make
pwd
/Users/kenorb/temp/foo
cd "/Users/kenorb/temp/foo/.."
pwd
/Users/kenorb/temp/foo
cd ".."
pwd
/Users/kenorb/temp/foo
```

It seems that `cd`'ing to parent directory via `..` doesn't take any effect.

How do I change the current working directory to a parent directory relatively to `Makefile` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has to do with the fact that each line of a rule's recipe is executed in a dedicated shell instance (i.e.: a new process). So, running `cd` in one line, won't have any effect for a command in another line, because these commands are executed by different processes.

#### Changing the working directory for a recipe

You can either use [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) (GNU Make 3.82 or later) to run all the recipe's lines in a single and the same shell instance:

```
CWD:=$(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

.ONESHELL:
all:
        pwd
        cd "$(CWD)/.."
        pwd
        cd ".."
        pwd
```

or just keep all the commands in a single line:

```
CWD:=$(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

all:
        pwd; cd "$(CWD)/.."; pwd; cd ".."; pwd
```

The change of the working directory takes effect **only inside** that recipe.

---

Note that changing the *current working directory* inside the makefile for the shell that invoked `make` is not possible, since that's a process' property, and the running `make` instance that will execute `cd` is another (sub)process. Therefore, it will only change the working directory of that subprocess.

That is the same reason you cannot change the working directory of a shell by executing a script without *sourcing* it: because the script runs in a new shell instance (i.e.: a subprocess).

Comment: Which version of GNU Make do you have?

Comment: `.ONESHELL` is avaliable as of GNU Make 3.82, you can still try the other alternative approach.